# Seeking advice for classifying 3d mobile data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, accelerometer, gyroscope

**Project**

I'm working on a project who's end goal will be to classify user input/behaviour on a smartphone, based on readings of 3D (accelerometer and gyroscope) movements (displacement, velocity, acceleration and jerk) as well as 2D interactions (velocity, acceleration, number of "touches" etc). My classifier will have to output whether the user is engaged/frustrated/perhaps other emotions subject to this [paper](http://iihm.imag.fr/publs/2012/Ubicomp12-IdentifyingEmotions-coutrix.pdf). These aren't necessary at this step however.

**Data**

The smartphone produces JSON files, with the position of the phone in terms of x, y and z, as well as the timestamp. There's a new timestamp every 20milliseconds.

**Idea**

I've done some Python tutorials and produced the code at the bottom so far. I've been advised to use NumPy and SciPy to make my life easier. Aside from the obvious kinematics, I need to include a filtering process. Google suggested Kalman filters.

**Question**

If anyone has experience in the matter, can they recommend an approach to this, perhaps you've encountered a similar project with a nice methodology.

```
import sqlalchemy
import json
import ReferenceFrame, get_motion_params, dynamicsymbols, symbols

con = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:@localhost/airlib')
meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData(bind=con, reflect=True)


dataObjects = []
dataAccObjects = []
dataGyroObjects = []

displacementChangeInX = []
displacementChangeInY = []
displacementChangeInZ = []


t = []  #time
v = []  #velocity
a = []  #acceleration
j = []  #jerk


results = meta.tables['rawmobiledata']


class DataEntry(object):
    item = 0
    time = 0
    x = 0
    y = 0
    z = 0

def __init__(self, item, time, x, y, z):
    self.item = item
    self.time = time
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z



def make_accelerometerEntry(item, time, x, y, z):
    dataAcc = DataEntry(item ,time, x, y, z)
    #print str(dataAccObjects)
    return dataAcc

def make_gyroEntry(item, time, x, y, z):
    dataGyro = DataEntry(item, time, x, y, z)
    #print str(dataGyroObjects)
    return dataGyro



for row in con.execute(results.select()):
        r = row[1]
        r = json.dumps(r)
        loaded_r = json.loads(r)
        #print(loaded_r)

        if loaded_r['sensor'] == 'accelerometer':
            for item in range(0, 250):
                time = loaded_r['data'][item]['time']
                x = loaded_r['data'][item]['x']
                y = loaded_r['data'][item]['y']
                z = loaded_r['data'][item]['z']
                dataAccObjects.append(make_accelerometerEntry(item, time, x, y, z))
                #print "this is an accelerometerObj"
        elif loaded_r['sensor'] == 'gyroscope':
            for item in range(0, 250):
                time = loaded_r['data'][item]['time']
                x = loaded_r['data'][item]['x']
                y = loaded_r['data'][item]['y']
                z = loaded_r['data'][item]['z']
                dataGyroObjects.append(make_gyroEntry(item, time, x, y, z))
                #print "gyroObj with time " + str(time) + ", reading " + str(item+1) + "/250, test#" + str((row[0]/2)+1)

for row in con.execute(results.select()):
        r = row[1]
        r = json.dumps(r)
        loaded_r = json.loads(r)
        if loaded_r['sensor'] == 'gyroscope':
            for item in range (0,250):
                #rate of change
                # ti = |t2-t1|
                t[item] = abs(int(dataGyroObjects[item].time) - int(dataGyroObjects[item+1].time))
                #calculate change in displacement over the 3 axes
                displacementChangeInX[item] = abs(int(dataGyroObjects[item].x) - int(dataGyroObjects[item+1].x))
                displacementChangeInY[item] = abs(int(dataGyroObjects[item].y) - int(dataGyroObjects[item+1].y))
                displacementChangeInZ[item] = abs(int(dataGyroObjects[item].z) - int(dataGyroObjects[item+1].z))
                # v = dx/dt
                v[item] = abs(t[item] - 0)

                #calculate acceleration
                # a = dv/dx

                #calculate jerk
                # j = da/dt
```